# ASP.net WebAPI produces Access-Control-Allow-Origin error after insert of new method

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I was walking throug the angular heroes tutorial and wanted to replace the in-memory-service with a real backend. I wanted to create an ASP.net WebAPI. The controller worked completly fine like this with my angular frontend:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class HeroesController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly List<Hero> heroes;

    static HeroesController()
    {
        heroes = new List<Hero>()
        {
            new Hero { id = 11, name = "Mr. Nice" },
            new Hero { id = 12, name = "Narco" }
       };
    }

    public IEnumerable<Hero> Get()
    {
        return heroes;
    }

    public Hero Get(int id)
    {
        return heroes.Find(x => x.id == id);
    }

    public Hero Post([FromBody] Hero hero)
    {
        hero.id = heroes.Max(x => x.id) + 1;
        heroes.Add(hero);
        return hero;
    }

    public void Put([FromBody] Hero hero)
    {
        Hero oldHero = heroes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == hero.id);
        if (oldHero != null)
        {
            heroes.Remove(oldHero);
            heroes.Add(hero);
        }
    }
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        Hero oldHero = heroes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
        if (oldHero != null)
        {
            heroes.Remove(oldHero);
        }
    }
}
```

Which was nice and cool until I tried to create a method which was not named like "get", "post", "put" or "delete". I thought I could insert another public method like this:

```
    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
```

From now on every method continued to work EXCEPT the post. When I wanted to trigger the post I got the following Messages:

> OPTIONS http://localhost:52835/api/heroes 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> Failed to load http://localhost:52835/api/heroes: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>
> ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 2, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}

Yeah, the angular frontend runs on port 4200 and the webapi on 52835. Therefor I have installed and activated CORS which workes very well until I added the mentioned empty method. If I change the method to private, everything works fine again. I don't get it. Please help me :(

Comment: First step is to check the server's logs to see what caused the 500. .NET will have thrown an exception of some sort. The rest of what you showed is all just symptoms of that crash, not causes. One question - which HTTP method is this new public method supposed to respond to? You'll notice that the others implicitly all map to a particular method due to the naming convention. But your new one doesn't. So unless you specify an explicit route to it (via a Route attribute, normally), then .NET is probably going to get confused about which public method it should run when the HTTP request is made

Comment: The reason it'll work again when you make it private is because .NET doesn't look for private methods when trying to map a HTTP request to a particular C# method in the controller, it only looks for public ones.

Comment: I suggest you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection#action-selection

Comment: And then you might want to follow it up with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: @ADyson thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adding the Http method like

```
[HttpPost]
public void DoSomething()
```

didn't work for me. The method was HttpPost by default (like you can read in the first link further down). And as I changed to HttpGet my get-Methods stopped working. It seams there's some kind of black magic in the background which trys to figure out which methods could fit to a type of http requests depending on the name and the signature of a method. And if I understood right, complex types (like my hero) won't be checked, so basically the signatures of my methods "Post" and "DoSomething" are equal. Therefor read the helping link of ADyson:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection#action-selection

If there's more than one method fitting, the black magic starts jumping out the window. With this said, what will help is changing the method's signature (of course). For example by adding a parameter of type int.

But I guess the better solution would be defining a route with the Route Annotation like this:

```
[Route("heroes/doSomething")] 
public void DoSomething()
```

Again thanks to ADyson (you are my hero ;) ):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

**Edit:**

Of course it's not black magic. As I read the linked pages, everything became clear. The logic is, methods which contain Post in theire names will serve post requests. And if the automatism can not derive a request type from the method name, then the method is automatically post. And if now two methods serve post requests, the automatism gets confused if no clear routes are given.

Comment: all correct, although it's a long way from black magic, it's just some simple rules based on naming convention (i.e. if your method name contains "Post" it'll use it to handle an incoming POST request). As you say it only falls apart if there unmapped methods or methods which otherwise cause the routing engine any uncertainty.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and what solved it for me was to decorate the method with the relevant decorator.

e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public void DoSomething()
{
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because there's already a method named "Post" and the Web API naming convention rules are enough to mean that method is already going to be used to handle POST requests to that controller. So doing this will still mean the routing engine will have trouble deciding which of the two available methods to use to handle the Post. From the evidence in the question it seems it would pick the original one with the "Post" name, but this failed for the OP because the posted request data didn't match that method signature's expectations. .NET won't then try the other method instead.